# Why does a large array constructor call break the Scala compiler?

Tags: arrays, scala, compiler-errors

I'm doing some image processing for a job and was scripting things with Im4Java. In order to write some unit cases I decided to just store a local image as a byte array in the code. I grabbed a simple test image

[image: Example Image Pulled from Wikipedia]

And then converted it to the byte array like so:

```
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
val stuff =scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileName)(scala.io.Codec.ISO8859).map(_.toByte).toArray
Files.write(Paths.get("tmp.txt"), stuff.mkString(",").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

And then put those bytes into an `Array[Byte]` apply constructor:

```
class testCase() {
    val smallFile = Array[Byte](-1,-40,-1, …) // 9816 arguments to the constructor passed here
}
```

When I tried to compile this (see the full scala file in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/EdgeCaseBerg/69f7146fcf738be54768)) I was surprised to see it break the compiler's typer! I get the following stacktrace (I've truncated it a bit):

```
[error] uncaught exception during compilation: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1241)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.baseTypeSeqLength$1(Symbols.scala:1628)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.isLess(Symbols.scala:1631)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.baseTypeIndex(Types.scala:992)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$CompoundType.baseType(Types.scala:1655)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassTypeRef$class.baseType(Types.scala:2186)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef$$anon$6.baseType(Types.scala:2544)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.firstTry$1(Types.scala:6064)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.isSubType2(Types.scala:6228)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.isSubType(Types.scala:5837)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.isSubType(SymbolTable.scala:13)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.fourthTry$1(Types.scala:6223)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.thirdTryRef$1(Types.scala:6123)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.thirdTry$1(Types.scala:6145)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.secondTry$1(Types.scala:6109)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.firstTry$1(Types.scala:6070)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.isSubType2(Types.scala:6228)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.isSubType(Types.scala:5837)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.isSubType(SymbolTable.scala:13)
at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.$less$colon$less(Types.scala:872)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:1091)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5660)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedArg(Typers.scala:3042)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.loop$1(Typers.scala:3069)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.loop$1(Typers.scala:3071)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.loop$1(Typers.scala:3071)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.loop$1(Typers.scala:3071)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.loop$1(Typers.scala:3071)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.loop$1(Typers.scala:3071)
(etc as this is where the stackoverflow happens)
```

I'm using the Scala 2.10.5 compiler and java jdk1.7.0_79

I'm probably going to just use a smaller image or something to fix my issue, but I would like to know why the compiler does this and if it can be fixed?

Comment: Normally, the image itself can't be the problem, since the compiler won't know about it at compile-time.

Comment: I doubt it has something to do with the actual image since error is thrown during compile time. Can you provide full version of code (it's unclear how `fileName`, `Files` and `Paths` are defined)?

Comment: @om-nom-nom see the gist file linked in the question.

Comment: @Clashsoft there is no actual problem with the image. I just provided the code so that someone could reproduce the byte array I was using in the gist file if they wanted to in the same way.

Comment: Maybe you hit the "64K bytecode per method" limit the JVM has? Or, well, you're passing a bit over 9000 arguments to that constructor; some sources seem to say there's a limit at 255.

Comment: So you actually have very long inlined definition of array

Comment: yes. I resized the image to 25x25 with imagemagick and I could use that byte array fine. 50x50 or 100x100 caused the crashes still though.
@Mauris do you have a citation for that limit? It would be good to have for a possible answer on how big an array can be for the compiler itself I think

Comment: The problem might be that the compiler has to check all these arguments for being compatible with `Byte`. I don't know exactly how the Scala Compiler does this, but the stack trace hints at a recursive method (which is, if you ask me, a very bad compiler design)

Comment: @Clashsoft that would be an interesting thing to bring up to the people who create the compiler. om nom nom's answer below suggests they fixed a few things up that at least gave a better error message. So maybe they already did? I'm not sure where I would go hunting for that information though. Or which mailing lists to scroll through

Comment: Simply don't, and please get rid of that array. If you *really* have to have that image in your source *code* (notice something :P), you might want to try Base64-encoded strings.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Clashsoft hadn't thought to use Base64 for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I tried to reproduce your problem and newer scalac (2.11.7) has a better error message (hope it clears up the problem):

```
» scalac Arrays.scala
Arrays.scala:1: error: Could not write class testCase because it exceeds JVM code size limits. Method <init>'s code too large!
class testCase()  {
      ^
one error found
```

So it looks like, just like [@Marius noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571846/why-does-a-large-array-constructor-call-break-the-scala-compiler/31572064#comment51098820_31571846), you're hitting "64K bytecode per method" limit imposed by JVM.

Comment: So it's looking like an answer to how big anything can be depends on those JVM settings? Which look like some of the limits are reference in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422480/maximum-size-of-a-method-in-java-7-and-8

Comment: Thanks @om-nom-nom this answers the question, but for clarity of an answer for anyone else who runs into this, could you edit your answer to explicitly state that it's a  JVM code size limit as well as showing the error from the compiler?