# TinkerPop running a very long length query crashes

Tags: tinkerpop3

**Massive Query** 3500~ characters:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Software").filter(hasId(8192,8193,8194,8195,8196,8197,8198,8199,8200,8201,8202,8203,8204,8205,8206,8207,8208,8209,8210,8211,8212,8213,8214,8215,8216,8217,8218,8219,8220,8221,8222,8223,8224,8225,8226,8227,8228,8229,8230,8231,8232,8233,8234,8235,8236,8237,8238,8239,8240,8241,8242,8243,8244,8245,8246,8247,8248,8249,8250,8251,8252,8253,8254,8255,8256,8257,8258,8259,8260,8261,8262,8263,8264,8265,8266,8267,8268,8269,8270,8271,8272,8273,8274,8275,8276,8277,8278,8279,8280,8281,8282,8283,8284,8285,8286,8287,8288,8289,8290,8291,8292,8293,8294,8295,8296,8297,8298,8299,8300,8301,8302,8303,8304,8305,8306,8307,8308,8309,8310,8311,8312,8313,8314,8315,8316,8317,8318,8319,8320,8321,8322,8323,8324,8325,8326,8327,8328,8329,8330,8331,8332,8333,8334,8335,8336,8337,8338,8339,8340,8341,8342,10197,2448,2449,2450,2451,2452,2453,2454,2455,2456,2457,2458,2459,2460,2461,2462,2463,2464,2465,2466,2467,2468,2469,2470,2471,2472,2473,2474,2475,2476,2477,2478,2479,2480,2481,2482,2483,2484,2485,2486,2487,2488,2489,2490,2491,2492,2493,2494,2495,2496,2497,2498,2499,2500,2501,2502,2503,2504,2505,2506,2507,2508,2509,2510,2511,2512,2513,2514,2515,2516,2517,2518,2519,2520,2521,2522,2523,2524,2525,2526,2527,2528,2529,2530,2531,2532,2533,2534,2535,2536,2537,2538,2539,2540,2541,2542,2543,2544,2545,2546,2547,2548,2549,2550,2551,2552,2553,2554,2555,2556,2557,2558,2559,2560,2561,2562,2563,2564,2565,2566,2567,2568,2569,2570,2571,2572,2573,2574,2575,2576,2577,2578,2579,2580,2581,2582,2583,2584,2585,2586,2587,2588,2589,2590,2591,2592,2593,2594,2595,2596,2597,2598,2599,2600,2601,2602,2603,2604,2605,2606,2607,2608,2609,2610,2611,2612,2613,2614,2615,2616,2617,2618,2619,2620,2621,2622,2623,2624,2625,7839,7840,7841,7842,7843,7844,7845,7846,7847,7848,7849,7850,7851,7852,7853,7854,7855,7856,7857,7858,7859,7860,7861,7862,7863,7864,7865,7866,7867,7868,7869,7870,7871,7872,7873,7874,7875,7876,7877,7878,7879,7880,7881,7882,7883,7884,7885,7886,7887,7888,7889,7890,7891,7892,7893,7894,7895,7896,7897,7898,7899,7900,7901,7902,7903,7904,7905,7906,7907,7908,7909,7910,7911,7912,7913,7914,7915,7916,7917,7918,7919,7920,7921,7922,7923,7924,7925,7926,7927,7928,7929,7930,7931,7932,7933,7934,7935,7936,7937,7938,7939,7940,7941,7942,7943,7944,7945,7946,7947,7948,7949,7950,7951,7952,7953,7954,7955,7956,7957,7958,7959,7960,7961,7962,7963,7964,7965,7966,7967,7968,7969,7970,7971,7972,7973,7974,7975,7976,7977,7978,7979,7980,7981,7982,7983,7984,7985,7986,7987,7988,7989,7990,7991,7992,7993,7994,7995,7996,7997,7998,7999,8000,8001,8002,8003,8004,8005,8006,8007,8008,8009,8010,8011,8012,8013,8014,8015,8016,8017,8018,8019,8020,8021,8022,8023,8024,8025,8026,8027,8028,8029,8030,8031,8032,8033,8034,8035,8036,8037,8038,8039,8040,8041,8042,8043,8044,8045,8046,8047,8048,8049,8050,8051,8052,8053,8054,8055,8056,8057,8058,8059,8060,8061,8062,8063,8064,8065,8066,8067,8068,8069,8070,8071,8072,8073,8074,8075,8076,8077,8078,8079,8080,8081,8082,8083,8084,8085,8086,8087,8088,8089,8090,8091,8092,8093,8094,8095,8096,8097,8098,8099,8100,8101,8102,8103,8104,8105,8106,8107,8108,8109,8110,8111,8112,8113,8114,8115,8116,8117,8118,8119,8120,8121,8122,8123,8124,8125,8126,8127,8128,8129,8130,8131,8132,8133,8134,8135,8136,8137,8138,8139,8140,8141,8142,8143,8144,8145,8146,8147,8148,8149,8150,8151,8152,8153,8154,8155,8156,8157,8158,8159,8160,8161,8162,8163,8164,8165,8166,8167,8168,8169,8170,8171,8172,8173,8174,8175,8176,8177,8178,8179,8180,8181,8182,8183,8184,8185,8186,8187,8188,8189,8190,8191))
.values("name")
```

A**nd it crashed badly, my guess is there is some kind of limit in the query length. If my assumption of length problem is correct, is there any work around for this???**

From Python I am running it like:

```
client = driver.Client(GREMLIN_URL, GREMLIN_VAR)
client.submit(query)
```

**Stacktrace**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/galaxia/Documents/bitbucket repo/ecodrone/ecodrone/test/test2.py", line 263, in <module>
    """))
  File "/home/galaxia/Documents/bitbucket repo/ecodrone/ecodrone/GremlinConnector.py", line 22, in execute_query
    results = future_results.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 405, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/galaxia/PycharmProjects/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/resultset.py", line 81, in cb
    f.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 398, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/galaxia/PycharmProjects/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py", line 77, in _receive
    self._protocol.data_received(data, self._results)
  File "/home/galaxia/PycharmProjects/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/protocol.py", line 106, in data_received
    "{0}: {1}".format(status_code, data["status"]["message"]))
gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 597: startup failed:
General error during class generation: 683

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 683
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.getCreateArraySignature(CallSiteWriter.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.makeCallSite(CallSiteWriter.java:317)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCachedCall(InvocationWriter.java:307)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:397)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeStaticMethod(InvocationWriter.java:515)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitStaticMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:807)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.StaticMethodCallExpression.visit(StaticMethodCallExpression.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.makeCallSite(CallSiteWriter.java:303)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCachedCall(InvocationWriter.java:307)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:397)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:464)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:771)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.prepareSiteAndReceiver(CallSiteWriter.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.prepareSiteAndReceiver(CallSiteWriter.java:224)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.makeCallSite(CallSiteWriter.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCachedCall(InvocationWriter.java:307)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:397)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:464)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:771)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeReturn(StatementWriter.java:590)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeReturn(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitReturnStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:620)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ReturnStatement.visit(ReturnStatement.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(StatementWriter.java:85)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBlockStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:570)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitStdMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:434)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitConstructorOrMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:387)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:511)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1081)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitClass(AsmClassGenerator.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$17.call(CompilationUnit.java:825)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1065)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:254)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:211)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine$2.lambda$load$0(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.asyncSupplyStage(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(CompletableFuture.java:1830)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine$2.load(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:164)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine$2.load(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:159)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalLoadingCache.lambda$new$0(BoundedLocalCache.java:3117)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.lambda$statsAware$0(LocalCache.java:144)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$16(BoundedLocalCache.java:1968)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1892)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:1966)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:1949)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:113)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalLoadingCache.java:67)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.getScriptClass(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:586)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:393)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eval$0(GremlinExecutor.java:263)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

1 error
```

---

Summary:

I am trying to do Vendor independent text search, and posted my problems in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893667/tinkerpop-vendor-independent-text-search) and [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/mJH-TWZ5T30).

It seemed pretty clear that there is no solution so such a thing, at the moment.

So I attempted to do this,

1. Fetch all values with

   g.V().hasLabel("software").project("id", "name").by(id()).by("name")
2. In do code perform text search
3. Fetch all those vertices by its mapped ids.

---

**Update**:

This seems

```
arr=[1,2,3,....n].toArray() 
g.V().filter(hasId(arr)).values("name")
```

and not this

```
g.V().filter(hasId(1,2,3,....n)).values("name")
```

Comment: Update it seems arr=[1,2,3,....n].toArray()   g.V().filter(hasId(arr)).values("name") this seems to be working fine, idk how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you send large scripts to Gremlin Server you can expect to see some problems. Large scripts have long compilation times and they can exceed the [maximum byte size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17422590/1831717) the JVM allows for a method. Your really long traversal string really doesn't need to be that long if you do something that you should be doing anyway - [parameterizing your queries](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#parameterized-scripts). First, let simplify your traversal:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Software").filter(hasId(8192,8193,8194....)).values("name")
```

is really just:

```
g.V().hasId(8192,8193,8194....).values("name")
```

If you have the actual vertex identifier then you already have the unique id and thus do not require the vertex label filter for "Software". We can then further simplify down to:

```
g.V(8192,8193,8194....).values("name")
```

Now, let's parameterize the script:

```
g.V(ids).values("name")
```

and sent from the gremlin-python driver the code looks like:

```
client.submit("g.V(ids).values('name')",{'ids':[8192,8193,8194....]}).next()
```

You will see a massive improvement in performance (especially on repeated calls) by taking this approach.

Comment: Thanks this helped me solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893667/tinkerpop-vendor-independent-text-search, feedbacks in it would be great